# How can I evaluate an IEnumerable<T> while giving special treatment to its first and/or last element in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

This is a more general form of the question, how can I do something special with the first and last element of a list?  The more specific question is easy to answer.  We know the index of the first and last element, so we can simply access them directly or test an index variable against those values.  For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; ++i)
{
  if (i == values.Count - 1)
  {
    // do something with last element
  }
  else
  {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

But sometimes I need to do a variation of this with an `IEnumerable<T>`.  For example:

```
public static Bar TransformFoo(Foo value)
{
  if (isLast /* how do we know this? */)
  {
    // do something with the last element
  }
  else
  {
    // do something else
  }    
}

public static IEnumerable<Bar> TransformFooSequence(IEnumerable<Foo> source)
{
  return source.Select(TransformFoo);
}
```

Since this is a common pattern, I'd like to solve it in a general way (rather than write a custom for loop for each case, as I have in the past).  One option would be to convert the sequence to a list using `ToList()` or count the elements using `Count()`.  The problem in both cases is that the solution involves evaluating the entire sequence, which can be prohibitively expensive.

So the question is, how can I evaluate an `IEnumerable<T>` sequence while giving special treatment to its first and/or last element while maintaining lazy evaluation of that sequence in a general way?

Comment: You definitely want to take a look at [how Linq does it](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,75722fd194dc2e0e).  It uses the IList cast to try to make it fast, so should you.  Do keep in mind that hiding a potential perf problem is never a very good idea.  So just make the parameter IList to get it over with.

Comment: What if the source doesn't naturally support IList?  For instance, imagine reading text files one line at a time.  Since each line is variable length, the number of lines in a file can't be known without reading the entire file.

Comment: You couldn't even know if it is the last line, you have to read one more.  Never try to hide an inconvenient truth.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of that comment.  Yes, if you want to mark the final element as "last" when using an input iterator, then you must read ahead by 1 and return the previous element on each iteration.  That's exactly how my solution below works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to create a new extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`that returns the elements of the source sequence along with semantic information about their positions.  If the elements of the source sequence have type `T`, then the extension method will return tuples of type `(T, PositionFlags)`.  Here's the code:

```
[Flags]
enum PositionFlags
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Last = 2
}    

public static IEnumerable<(T value, PositionFlags flags)> WithPositions<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }

        T value = enumerator.Current;
        PositionFlags flags = PositionFlags.First;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return (value, flags);

            value = enumerator.Current;
            flags = PositionFlags.None;
        }

        flags |= PositionFlags.Last;

        yield return (value, flags);
    }
}
```

We can then pass along the position information to give special treatment to the first and/or last item in a sequence.  For example:

```
Bar TransformFoo(Foo value, bool isLast)
{
    if (isLast)
    {
        // do something with the last element
     }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }     
}

IEnumerable<Bar> TransformFooSequence(IEnumerable<Foo> source)
{
  return source
      .WithPositions()
      .Select(entry => TransformFoo(
          entry.value,
          (entry.flags & PositionFlags.Last) == PositionFlags.Last));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an Enumerable.Select method that passes an element's index into the selector `Func` along with the element itself.  You can pass the current index into the function along with the total items (or last index value) so that the function has the information required to handle the special items.

```
var source = {some IEnumerable<Foo>};
var count = source.Count();

source.Select( ( item, i ) => TransformFoo( item, i, count ) );

public static Bar TransformFoo( Foo item, int index, int totalItems )
{
    if( 0 == index )
    {
        // first item handling
    }
    else if( ( index + 1 ) == totalItems )
    {
        // last item handling
    }
    else
    {
        // default item handling
    }
}
```

Or calculate the first/last flags in the select expression:

```
source.Select( ( item, i ) => TransformFoo( item, i == 0, i == ( totalItems - 1 ) );

public static Bar TransformFoo( Foo item, bool isFirst, bool isLast )
...
```

Comment: This is a fair answer to the question as I posed it.  But as I elaborated above, I don't want to force early evaluation of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

An `IEnumerable<>` may be an unordered set. Properly designed, your function should require an `IList<>` to indicate that the input will be treated as an ordered set.

If for some reason you must expose the parameter as an `IEnumerable<>`, in 99% of cases you should simply convert it to a `List<>` for processing. Your team should be focusing on its core business rather than writing the most fancy code for little details like this one.

If you have landed in an amazingly rare situation where you must take an input parameter that is defined as an `IEnumerable<>` AND it is extremely costly to convert to a list, you can use the enumerator directly to get the elements and treat them any way you want.

This method will iterate a generic list and call `first()`, `middle()`, and `last()` on the element depending on its position.

```
public static bool DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> first, Action<T> middle, Action<T> last)
{
    T current = default(T);
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    bool ok = enumerator.MoveNext();
    if (!ok) return false; //There were no elements
    var firstElement = enumerator.Current;
    ok = enumerator.MoveNext();
    if (!ok) return false; //There was only 1 element
    first(firstElement);
    while (ok)
    {
        current = enumerator.Current;
        ok = enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (ok) middle(current);
    }
    last(current);
    return true; 
}
```

Example calling it:

```
DoSomething
(
    myList,
    e => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("First: {0}", e)),  //This will run only for the first element
    e => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Middle: {0}", e)), //This will be output several times
    e => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Last: {0}", e))  //This will run only on the last element
);
```

This method handles any type and allows you to pass a delegate for each of the first, middle, and last elements. You didn't say how to handle the case if there aren't enough elements (you need three or more). In this example, if the set doesn't have enough elements to process in this fashion, none of them are processed, and the method returns `false`. Otherwise it returns true.

You can see it run with several test cases in my working example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TiV7or)

I would probably wrap this sort of logic in a class. For example, if you were writing a piece of code to process large flat files that had a header, detail, and footer section, maybe you'd write a base class like this, and inherit your file processors from it:

```
internal abstract class ReportBase
{
    protected readonly IEnumerable<string> _file;

    public ReportBase(IEnumerable<string> file)
    {
        _file = file;   
    }

    public bool Process()
    {
        return ProcessInternal(_file, ProcessHeader, ProcessDetail, ProcessFooter);
    }

    protected bool ProcessInternal<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> first, Action<T> middle, Action<T> last)
    {
        T current = default(T);
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        bool ok = enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (!ok) return false; //There were no elements
        var firstElement = enumerator.Current;
        ok = enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (!ok) return false; //There was only 1 element
        first(firstElement);
        while (ok)
        {
            current = enumerator.Current;
            ok = enumerator.MoveNext();
            if (ok) middle(current);
        }
        last(current);
        return true; //At l
    }

    abstract protected void ProcessHeader(string header);

    abstract protected void ProcessDetail(string header);

    abstract protected void ProcessFooter(string header);
}
```

On the other hand, you could avoid this whole mess if you asked the caller to pass you the elements separately, since it presumably knows which is which.

```
public void KeepItSimpleStupid<T>(T firstItem, IEnumerable<T> middleItems, T lastItem)
{
    firstItem.Foo();
    foreach (var item in middleItems) item.Bar();
    lastItem.Foo();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't IList also require mutability and random access?  That feels like overkill if all I want to imply is partial ordering.

Comment: @John Wu, you have a bug in the code :) move first(element) further up, looked at the testcase for "ONE" and it is wrong in the fiddle, I made an edit but it was overwritten

Comment: @PeterRuderman Hard to judge without knowing what the competing concerns are. Too much work to implement? It's likely the caller has the stuff in concrete objects anyway.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea That is not a bug, that is by careful design. The execution for any of the elements do not run unless the entire set is valid, i.e. has two or more elements. This allows the caller to read the return value and ensure atomic success or failure.

Comment: @John Wu, Ah, I see! I must have missed that in the requirements. My understanding was that any incoming items should be processed. I would agree it is a corner case - one could argue that 3 or more are needed in that case, I just have nightmares of people copying code off SO without knowing what's what, and spawning other SO questions with "My IEnumerable is not working properly with 1 item" :)

Comment: I read your edit, it makes more sense now :) keeping the upvote

Comment: It is a requirement to process every element in the list.  It's not clear to me what the correct behaviour should be when the list contains a single element using this approach.

Comment: I agree; it is a requirement to process every element in the list, and if the list can't be processed, it should fail. I also assume that a list without sufficient elements is not valid, and an invalid list should result in a failure. I take as an assumption that partial execution is a poor failure mode in general.

Comment: Fair enough, but to be fully general, the algorithm should allow for scenarios where a sequence of a single element is valid.  In such a sequence, the single element is both first and last.  There are use cases where we'd like to apply both the special "first" treatment and the special "last" treatment to that element.

Comment: @PeterRuderman Sure thing. You can replace `return false; //There was only 1 element` with any logic you wish, that's why I commented it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to handle the last element separately :

```
var last = source.Aggregate((previous, current) => {
    HandleNotLast(previous); 
    return current; }); 

HandleLast(last);
```

There isn't easy way to handle both first and last separately using LINQ extensions. For that you will need enumerator. There are MoreLINQ extensions such as [`TagFirstLast`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TagFirstLast.cs), but most of them seem to get the count of elements before enumerating.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  I'll definitely keep this one in my back pocket.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
public static Bar TransformFoo(Foo value)
{
    if (isLast /* how do we know this? */)
```

**You can't know this, because you didn't specify that Foo is always an object in a sequence**

You could change the meaning of Foo into: **a Foo is an object that ..., which is always a part of a sequence of Foos**, in which case it would be expected that every `Foo` has functionality to get access to sequence that it belongs to.

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    IEnumerable<Foo> GetSequence(); // returns the sequence that this Foo belongs to
}
```

If you think it is quite normal for `Foo` objects not to be part of a sequence, than you should not add this function. Instead you should add functionality to the sequence of `Foos`.

Let's extend `IEnumerable` with a new LINQ function. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Transform<TSource, Tresult>(
   this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
   Func<TSource, TResult> transformFuncNonLastElement,
   Func<TSource, TResult> transformFuncLansElement)
{
     // for every element: check if it is the last one,
     // if not, yield return transformFuncNonLastElement
     // if last: yield return transformFuncLastElement
     IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

     if (enumerator.MoveNext())
     {   // There is at least one element.
         TSource current = enumerator.Current;

         // while current is not the last one: transformFuncNonLastElement
         while (enumerator.MoveNext())
         {
             // current is not the last one
             TResult transformedNonLastValue = transformFuncNonLastElement(current);
             yield return transformedNonLastValue;

             current = enumerator.Current;
         }

         // if here: there are no more elements. current is the last one
         TResult transformedLastValue = transformFuncLastElement(current);
         yield return transformedLastValue;
     }
     // else: input sequence empty: return empty
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> myFoos = ...
IEnumerable<Bar> result = myFoors.Transform(
   foo => ToNonLastBar(foo),
   foo => ToLastBar(foo));
```

Where:

```
Bar ToNonLastBar(Foo foo) {...}
Bar ToLastBar(Foo foo) {...}
```